# Construct self-complementary graph

Tags: graph-theory, algebraic-graph-theory

Given a graph, is there any algorithm to build from it a self-complementary graph, by adding edges and vertices? I'm also interested in minimizing the number of added nodes.

Thank you!

Answer (score 6):

Say you have a graph $G$, with complement $G^c$. Create a new graph:
$$G \equiv G^c \equiv G^c \equiv G$$
where $H_1 \equiv H_2$ means that every vertex in $H_1$ is connected to every vertex in $H_2$. Then this graph is self complementary (why?) and since it contains a copy of $G$, it can be built up from $G$.

Comment: this is a good theoretical answer, but I imagine an algorithm based on this would not be efficient

Comment: Yes, that's a good answer. However, I'm interested in minimizing the number of added nodes. Is there any other method (including the probabilistic ones, if there are any) to build such a graph?